# How to remove an environment variable on GitHub actions?

Tags: github-actions

#### Context

On https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables
they describe a way to add an environment variable with yaml:

```yaml
jobs:
  job_name:
    env:
      NAME: value
```

On https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions/#setting-an-environment-variable linked from the same place, shows how to add an environment variable from script steps:

```sh
echo "NAME=value" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

#### Question

*I'm looking for a way to do the opposite: given that an env var was added with one of the above options, **fully remove it** so that subsequent job steps don't see it either.*

I tried

```sh
echo "NAME=" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

but it just sets it to empty string, I need it gone so that `env` doesn't list it any more.

#### Resources

Raised it GitHub community too: https://github.community/t/remove-environment-variable-from-job/214815

Comment: Do you change a lot of other variables between setting and removing `NAME`. A somewhat brute force way to do this would be to save a copy of `GITHUB_ENV` prior to adding `NAME` and then overwrite the new one with the copy once you are done using `NAME`.

Comment: `GITHUB_ENV` points to a file, are you suggesting I could `sed` the variable out of it? Note: the variable was not set by me, it was set by one of the `uses` steps.

Comment: Nope @Tyberius, the file pointed by `$GITHUB_ENV` is changing between every step. It only records the delta to be propagated to `env.`, does not contain existing variables.

Comment: Interesting question! I was wondering: as you can use env variable at different levels (workflow, jobs and steps)... Why not add this variable as output on an initial step, and only use the output as env variable on specific steps through the syntax `env: NAME: ${{ steps.<step_id>.outputs.<output_name> }}`, (or in other jobs) instead of adding it to the `$GITHUB_ENV`. Wouldn't it be an option?

Comment: Nope, @GuiFalourd, I'm not the one creating this env var, but it's a nice workaround for that case. I'll keep this in mind for other CIs because I've been communicating with env vars everywhere...

Comment: Hey @TWiStErRob were you able to solve this? I'm struggling with the same problem

Comment: @AvijitGupta Nope, as far as I remember I was able to work around by changing the logic (`if` on a previous step that created it) to make sure it's not created.